# Hide keyboard by touching background of UITableViewContoller

Tags: uitableview, swift

Would like to hide the keyboard while touching on the background of UITableViewContoller. At the moment I have implemented removing keyboard while pressing return but while pressing outside somewhere still not working. My code:

```
class SecondViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
    // Hide Keyboard while pressing return
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        tb_Name.resignFirstResponder()
        tb_Description.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }

    // Hide Keyboard while pressing somewhere on the UI
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Strange thing is, when I add this code in a "normal" view controller, then it works fine. In an Table View Contoller not.

Thx.

Comment: It's not really a way to tap to dismiss, but if you're targeting iOS 7 and up, you can set the tableView's `keyboardDismissMode` property to OnDrag or Interactive to dismiss the keyboard with interaction on the tableView. `tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag`

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try to add a gesture on it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)]; 
tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; 
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
```

And actually there are so many ways to handle that, it really depends on what you desired behaviors.